# DNN multiple modules on a single package

Tags: c#, asp.net, module, dotnetnuke, manifest

Is it possible to create a dotnetnuke (v5) package that contains multiple modules?
I mean: there is a "moduleDefinitions" element on the manifest that looks like supporting more than one module, but adding another child to it doesn't sort any effect.

The dnn manifest looks like:

```
<dotnetnuke type="Package" version="5.0">
<packages>
    <package name="MyModuleName" type="Module" version="01.00.00">
        <friendlyName>MyModuleName</friendlyName>
        <components>
            <component type="Module">
                <desktopModule>
                    <moduleName>MyModuleName</moduleName>
                    <foldername>MyModuleName</foldername>
                    <supportedFeatures />
                    <businessControllerClass />
                    <moduleDefinitions>
                        <moduleDefinition>...</moduleDefinition>
                        <!-- this one is ignored -->
                        <moduleDefinition>...</moduleDefinition>
                    <moduleDefinitions>
```

Anyway I need to package two or more modules on the same package. Is it possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Multiple module definition elements should work just fine.  If there are multiple definitions within a module, when you add the module to the page, an instance of each definition will be added.  There will still only be one entry in the extensions list.

If you want two independent modules, you will need two `<package>` elements (it *won't* work to have two `<component type="Module">` elements in a `<package>`).

Comment: I tried all the alternatvies and yes the double <package> element did the job. thanks for the answer!

Comment: multiple packages creates multiple instances in extensions page, is it possible to have 1 single package with multiple modules?

Comment: @dvdnhm, no, DNN doesn't currently support having multiple modules within a single package (you can vote for that support at http://www.dnnsoftware.com/voice/cid/419081 if you think it's worth investing in)

Comment: @bdukes, I did vote for it, I hope guys add this feature soon.